# SQLAlchemy: MySQL column DDL with GENERATED ALWAYS AS

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to replicate this column with sqlalchemy orm (MySQL):

`` `line_price_taxed` decimal(20,4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`quantity` * `unit_price_taxed`)) STORED, ``

my attempt so far has been:

`` line_price_taxed = Column(DECIMAL(20, 4), server_default=text('''GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`quantity` * `unit_price_taxed`)) STORED'''), index=True) ``

but I get this error:
`` 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`quantity` * `unit_price_taxed`)) STORED ``

Is there a way to pass raw SQL into the sqlalchemy ORM model?

Answer (score 5):

According to the SQLAlchemy documentation, if you are using a version higher than `1.3.11`

You can use `Computed`
For example,

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Computed

line_price_taxed = Column(DECIMAL(20, 4), Computed("quantity * unit_price_taxed"), index=True)
```

you can find the tutorial from [SQLAlchemy Computed (GENERATED ALWAYS AS) Columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#computed-generated-always-as-columns)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that sqlalchemy automatically prepends the word `DEFAULT` into the column definition before your `GENERATED ALWAYS AS...` if you pass it to the `server_default` arg.

Nothing stood out to me as immediately obvious in the [`Column API`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.__init__) as a way to do this, but I did come across [this example](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/ddl.html#sqlalchemy.schema.CreateColumn) where a custom compiler is used to inject some "SPECIAL DIRECTIVES" into the create column clause if the column's `info` dict has some particular key. It can be easily modified to achieve your desired column definition, for example:

```py
from sqlalchemy_app import Base, engine
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy import schema
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DECIMAL
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

class Model(Base):

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    unit_price_taxed = Column(DECIMAL(20, 4), nullable=False)
    line_price_taxed = Column(
        DECIMAL(20, 4),
        info={
            "generated_stmt": "GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`quantity` * `unit_price_taxed`)) STORED"
        },
        index=True,
    )


@compiles(schema.CreateColumn)
def compile(element, compiler, **kw):
    column = element.element
    if "generated_stmt" not in column.info:
        return compiler.visit_create_column(element, **kw)
    col_name = column.name
    col_type = compiler.type_compiler.process(column.type)
    text = f"{col_name} {col_type} {column.info['generated_stmt']}"
    return text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

`Model.line_price_taxed` is passed `info={"generated_stmt": <stmt text>}` and the custom compiler looks for that key to see if it needs to do the special handling. If found it renders the value of that key in line.

Have a look at the linked example as I've left out handling of column defaults, not null and constraints that is included over there.

Here's the engine logs for the above script:

```
2019-08-22 11:50:51,740 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine
CREATE TABLE model (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
        unit_price_taxed DECIMAL(20, 4) NOT NULL,
        line_price_taxed DECIMAL(20, 4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`quantity` * `unit_price_taxed`)) STORED,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


2019-08-22 11:50:51,741 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-08-22 11:50:51,796 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
2019-08-22 11:50:51,797 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine CREATE INDEX ix_model_line_price_taxed ON model (line_price_taxed)
2019-08-22 11:50:51,798 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
2019-08-22 11:50:51,838 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine COMMIT
```